# Mostrar grafica en matplotlib antes de que termine el programa

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy realizando un proyecto en python y utilizo matplotlib para graficar pero al momento de ejecutarlo no me muestra la grafica sino hasta el final del menu repetitivo.

```
def graficar(x,y,xp,yp):
   plt.plot(x, y, color='#00ff00', label='Regression')
   plt.scatter(xp, yp, color='#ff0000', label='Data Point')
   plt.xlabel('X')
   plt.ylabel('Y')
   plt.legend()
```

El menu tiene las opciones: \

```
def Menu():#menu principal
op=1#variable para moverse por el menu
while(op):
    op=int(input("Menu\n1.Ingreso de datos\n2.ajuste por minimos cuadrados\n3.ajuste exponencial\n4.ajuste polinomial\n5.Salir\nescoge una opcion: "))
    while(op<0 or op>5):
        op=int(input("ingrese una opcion valida: "))#vuelve a preguntar la opcion
    if (op==1):
        print("Ingrese los valores de X separados por un espacio y precione enter, de la siguiente manera:1 2 3 . . ")
        x=[float(x) for x in input("X=").split()]#crea una lista con los datos ingresados 
        print("Ingrese los valores de Y separados por un espacio y precione enter, de la siguiente manera:1 2 3 . . ")
        y=[float(y) for y in input("Y=").split()]
    elif(op==2):
        try:
            print("\n\nminimos cuadrados\n\n")
            x_graf,y_graf=reg_l.reg_lineal(x,y)
            graficar(x_graf,y_graf,x,y)
        except UnboundLocalError:
            print("primero ingresa los datos")
        except IndexError:
            print("Para poder realizar el calculo debes ingresar correctamente los datos")  
    #Mas graficas pero con otras listas 
                         
    elif(op==5):
        print("Fin del programa")
        op=0
```

pero no lo grafica hasta que le doy a salir y despues

Comment: Te recomiendo adjuntar más código.